# Html Agility Pack isn't matching <link> tags

Tags: .net, html, xpath

Code: (Using HTML Agility Pack)

```
 Dim moHtmlParser As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument           
 moHtmlParser.LoadHtml(htmlString)
           
 Dim maStyles As New List(Of String)
 Dim moStyleNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = moHtmlParser.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link")
```

Html:

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="Scripts/JScript1.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        
<link href="Stylesheets/StyleSheet1.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="Stylesheets/StyleSheet2.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="Stylesheets/StyleSheet3.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
     

<title>Untitled Page</title>
```

No matches?  moStyleMatches is always Nothing.  The Html shown is from the Head, for what it's worth.  I'm able to match other tags in there(script, title) no problem.

#### Update:

Even after removing the ElementsFlag for "link" tags, it just wouldn't pick up the tags.

I worked around it with this code:

```
Dim moStyleNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = moHtmlParser.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@rel]")
```

I then made sure that the "rel" was "stylesheet" before working with the node.

Works for now, but doesn't explain why it wasn't working in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, ya it's the HTML Agility Pack.  Probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: Now that I'm reading it again though...what else would you like to see?  The rest of my code is just working with the moStyleNodes object, but it's always empty anyways

Comment: Interesting.  Let me edit to add the full <head> html, as I can match other tags in there.

Comment: Could be a problem with the closing `/>`. AFAIK this is xhtml-style, not html.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation of the most probable cause of this problem and for a summary of the solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after removing the ElementsFlag for "link" tags, it just wouldn't pick up the tags.

I worked around it with this code:

```
Dim moStyleNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = moHtmlParser.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@rel]")
```

I then made sure that the "rel" was "stylesheet" before working with the node.

Works for now, but doesn't explain why it wasn't working in the first place.

Comment: This should be an update to your question. Check @Dimitre correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

**This is most probably a default namespace problem** -- most likely a default namespace in the complete document, that you have not shown.

**Writing XPath expressions that address names that are in no namespace is a FAQ** and there are numerous good answers in the xpath tag -- just find and read them.

**In summary**, XPath considers any non-prefixed name in an XPath expression to be in "no namespace". Because the actual elements in the XML document *are* in the default namespace (not in no namespace), they are not selected.

**The solution** is to register a namespace binding using the API of your XPath engine and then prefix all names in the expression with the preffix from the binding.

**See [this](http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=281) for more information** exactly how to register a namespace in SimpleXML.